# Using zend framework with angular 6

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework, angular6

I have a project of social media its in zend framework . I have to develop activity feeds like facebook in angular. So only angularjs is possible or i can use angular 6 also. I dont know about integration of this two

Comment: Yep you can do it with both angular and angularjs . Integration depends on the approach you choose. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688397/how-to-show-continuous-real-time-updates-like-facebook-ticker-meetup-com-home-p) might help you get started

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way to go is to create a REST API using Zend Framework and make a separate Angular 6 project that consumes web services provided by your API. To this end, if you use Zend Framework 2 or 3, you can easily integrate [Apigility](https://apigility.org) in your project to serve JSON data. In the Angular side, you just use the HttpClient class to make api calls and receive your data. The following [link](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-5-making-api-calls-httpclient-service) explains this clearly (just skip the backend api section because it's based on express). I hope this gives you a glimpse on what can be done.